# Expectation of a Chi-squared distribution

Tags: expectation

I am to find out the value of this expectation : $$E \bigg(\frac{U^p}{U+V} \bigg),$$ where $U \sim \chi^2_1$ and $V \sim \chi^2_n$. $U$ and $V$ are independent.

Can anyone give me any hints about how to start this problem ?